# Swift Memory Leak, ARC

Tags: swift, memory-management, mvvm, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am working with an MVVM structure where the viewController communicates with a viewModel via binding and the viewModel communicates with a Model via notifications.

I am creating the viewModels at the function level so that once I am done with them they are deallocated:

```
func getInformation(){
    var viewModel = thisViewModel()
    var requestStatus = customEnum.notRequested
    viewModel.status.bind{
    requestStatus = customEnum.notRequested
    switch $0{
        case .success:
              self.data = viewModel.results
        default: break
    }
   requestStatus = customEnum.Requested
}
```

However, it seems that their Models still exist after the function exits and after a few calls of `getInformation()` I start getting swamped by responses, indicating a memory leak (i.e. each still existing model is still listening for and responding to the viewModel request).

I am also dealocatting the models once the viewModels have finished using them:

```
class thisViewModel {
    var model: myModel!

    init(){
         model = myModel()
    }

    func getStuff(){
        //Do cool stuff here
        model = nil
    }
}
```

I can avoid the response duplication by removing the NotificationCenter observer in the model but how do I resolve the memory leak that this is causing?

EDIT:

By changing the bind in getInformation to:

```
viewModel.status.bind { [weak requestStatus] in
```

I was able to get the model to start deallocating but the viewModel is still sticking around. I believe this is because the bind statement is needed even after the function ends but once one of the switch cases is triggered it is no longer needed so it needs to be released then.